# Scala Programming Language: What's the diff b/w : 1) Var immutable Map, Val mutable Map & Var mutable Map?

Tags: scala

> **What's the diff b/w : 1) Var immutable Map, Val mutable Map & Var mutable Map?**

[The image attached here is of the same code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rqz2.png)

Also, why are all these definitions of a Map acting as if they are mutable?

```
scala> var var_m_map =  collection.mutable.Map(("key1",1), ("key2",2))
var_m_map: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(key2 -> 2, key1 -> 1)

scala> var_m_map += ("key30" -> 30)
res8: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(key30 -> 30, key2 -> 2, key1 -> 1)

scala> val val_m_map =  collection.mutable.Map(("key10",10), ("key20",20))
val_m_map: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(key20 -> 20, key10 -> 10)

scala> var_m_map += ("key30" -> 30)
res9: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(key30 -> 30, key2 -> 2, key1 -> 1)


scala> var var_i_map =  collection.immutable.Map(("key100",100), ("key200",200))
var_i_map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(key100 -> 100, key200 -> 200)

scala> var_i_map += ("key300" -> 300)

scala> var_i_map
res11: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(key100 -> 100, key200 -> 200, key300 -> 300)

scala> var var_i_map2 = Map(("key700",700), ("key800",800))
var_i_map2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(key700 -> 700, key800 -> 800)

scala> var_i_map2 += ("key900" -> 900)

scala> var_i_map2
res13: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(key700 -> 700, key800 -> 800, key900 -> 900)
```

Comment: Note that 'var' means the reference is mutable. It doesn't mean the object referred to is mutable. 'val' means the reference is immutable. And adding to an immutable map will return you a new map with your added element

Answer (score 0):

`var var_i_map` is a **mutable** reference to an **immutable** Map.

`+=` adds an element to the immutable map currently bound to `var_i_map` which returns a new immutable map instance. This new instance is the (re)assigned to `var_i_map`.

Note the immutable collection originally bound to `var_i_map` is not changed, the mutable var is being changed.

Change `var var_i_map` to `val var_i_map` and your code will not compile because you are attempting to change an imutable val.